# How to connect the Blockchain to the Network without IP Address?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain

**I would like to know how do we connect the blockchain to the network when there is no IP?**
Indeed we all use bitcoin core (for bitcoin) to connect and retrieve information and update.
However the source code of bitcoin core (I have never read it) does not redirect us to an IP address, but people still manage to find themselves, without ever saving the IP.
How can people know or find the information, when the source code of the software does not have IP, they do not know address (IP) which has the information?
Knowing that the IP is the basis of the connection ...

Answer (score 1):

The bitcoin client has many means to discover other ip in the bitcoin network, in the case of DNS request, which will return many ip address each times, here are the diferent DNS used as in 2017:

> seed.bitcoin.sipa.be dnsseed.bluematt.me dnsseed.bitcoin.dashjr.org
>   seed.bitcoinstats.com seed.bitcoin.jonasschnelli.ch
>   seed.btc.petertodd.org

You can see all the methods used by the bitcoin client to discover nodes here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Satoshi_Client_Node_Discovery

Comment: if this is the case, it means that bitcoin core will no longer work for new clients (who have never started it), if the DNS is unavailable.

Is it a certain way of centralization? : /

Comment: If all those hardcoded DNS became unavailable, you will soon see all kind of post on every media, like facebook or even here posting new DNS to connect to, there is even nodes in space now https://cointelegraph.com/news/bitcoin-in-space-blockchain-satellite-receives-first-transaction good luck shutting all of them down ;)

Comment: OK i understand, very thank !